# Parameterize JMeter recording

Tags: parameters, jmeter, recording

I am trying to run a recording and parameterize it so that it can grab the username, password, and requisition number from a spreadsheet.  One of the steps ctl00_ctl00_body_PageMainContent_ctl00_ContractingOfficer_ClientState has an entry hardcoded {"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":"","validationText":"DRULE","valueAsString":"DRULE","lastSetTextBoxValue":"DRULE"}  I tried to replace "DRULE" with the variable ${UserName} in all places and it failed, I also tried replacing the lastSetTextBoxValue and it also failed.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) to your Test Plan (if you're using [Recording Template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions) it should already be there) and define `UserName` variable with the value of `DRULE` there:

[image]

Once you do this all occurrences of `DRULE` in the requests will be replaced with `${UserName}`

With regards to your `ctl00_ctl00_body_PageMainContent_ctl00_ContractingOfficer_ClientState` parameter I believe it needs to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

Comment: I am using a CSV Data Set Config item so that I can have different users log in and perform the actions